# How to fix large reboot/shutdown time?

Tags: kubuntu, lenovo, chromebook, 23.04

I am using Ubuntu Kubuntu 23.04 on Lenovo Chromebook 500e 2nd edition with the MrChromebox.Tech custom UEFI.

While everything works, sometimes, it takes almost a minute for the computer to shutdown.
How to fix the issue?

I don't know which logs I should look at to begin with.

The computer has an SSD, and the startup time is about 14 seconds.

This is the message shown.

```
Broadcast message from user@computer on pts/1 (system time):
The system will reboot now
```

**Update**: If I normally reboot/shut down via GUI, it does not take much time. But if I run `reboot` or `poweroff` commands, it takes a lot more time.

Comment: when you shutdown, press escape. 
look at the terminal an see if you get a message about waiting to unmount a filesysrtem, or waiting for a device.

Comment: The situation comes up occasionally. Today it happened, and nothing happened when I pressed escape

Comment: any services you added to the system?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I edited the question. If I normally reboot/shut down via GUI, it does not take much time. But if I run `reboot` or `poweroff` commands, it takes a lot more time.